# Is this minimizing problem NP-hard?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard, arrays, polynomial-time-reductions

We have $c$ arrays of positive integers, named $j[1],j[2],j[3]..,j[c]$. We know that the length of $j[i]$ is $c-i+1$. In addition, the sum of the numbers of $j[i]$ is greater than or equal to the sum of numbers of $j[y]$ if $i \leq y$. Moreover, we have $k$ tuples, each with a length of at most $c$. If we use a tuple $i=(i_1,i_2,...i_l)$, we will decrease each of $j[1][i_1],j[2][i_2],j[3][i_3],...,j[l][i_l]$ by one. If $j[p]$'s length was less than $i_p$, we just skip decreasing $j[p][i_p]$. Our goal is to use a minimum number of tuples such that in each array $j[i]$, the number $j[i][i]$ be the minimum. Is it an NP-hard problem?

Please notice that values cannot go less than 0. Moreover, we want that $j[1][1]$ to be the minimum in $j[1]$, $j[2][2]$ be the minimum in $j[2]$, etc.

Comment: I don't understand the problem statement.  1. There might be one solution that makes j[1][1] small and another that makes j[2][2] small, but no solution that makes both of them be the minimum.  In that case I'm not sure what the desired solution is.  2. Can values decrease below zero and go negative?

Comment: We want that each of them is the minimum in their array: j[1][1] to be the minimum in j[1], j[2][2] to be the minimum in j[2], etc. You can just consider that always there exists a solution for it. Please consider that the values cannot go below 0.

Comment: Thank you.  Please [edit] your post to clarify.  Please don't put clarifications in the comments -- instead, revise the post so that it is clear to someone who encounters it for the first time, and so they don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.